# Add Enter key as JButton accelerator

Tags: java, swing

I'm building simple chat application with simple GUI, but a I have a problem assigning Enter key to Send button. Right now it is quite unpractical pressing Alt+Enter.

```
public void buildInterface() {
   //some other components
    btnSend = new JButton("Send");
    btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
    btnSearch=new JButton("Search");
    btnSend.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); 

     JPanel box=new JPanel();
     add(box, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
     box.add(tfInput);
     box.add(btnSend);
     box.add(btnExit);
     box.add(btnSearch);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When the button is focused, under most look and feels the <kbd>Enter</kbd> will activate the button.

You can, however, assign a button to be the "default" button for the window, which will be activated when the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key pressed, so long as the focused component does not consume it.

See [How to Use Root Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) and [`JRootPane#setDefaultButton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JRootPane.html#setDefaultButton-javax.swing.JButton-) for more details

Answer (score 1):

Add following code to your Util class

```
public static void bindKeyStroke(final JButton btn, String ks) {
    final ActionListener[] alist = btn.getActionListeners();
    if (alist.length != 0) {
        AbstractAction action = new AbstractAction(btn.getText(), btn.getIcon()) {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (ActionListener al : alist) {
                    ActionEvent ae = new ActionEvent(e.getSource(), e.getID(), Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY);
                    al.actionPerformed(ae);
                }
            }
        };

        KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(ks);
        btn.setAction(action);
        btn.getActionMap().put(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY, action);
        btn.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(keyStroke, Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY);
    }
}
```

Goto frame, dialog or panel constructor and add after initComponent();

```
Util.bindKeyStroke(<your button>, "alt enter");
```

Fix double action, in action performed

```
if (evt.getActionCommand().equals(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY)) {
    // Your send action here
}
```